# How to generate entities and cruds in SF4?

Tags: php, symfony4

I've just installed symfony 4 and after noticing the structure being slightly different, searching for some config files and editing around a bit, I was planning to go and generate my first entities and cruds.

However, I found that symfony 4 does no longer support the `doctrine:generate:entity` command.

Instead I found that symfony now offers the `MakerBundle` that comes with a range of simple commands to generate the most basic code snippets.

What I am wondering is if there is still a way to interactively generate an entity and/or crud.

I tried installing the `SensioGeneratorBundle` but that doesn't yet seem compatible with symfony 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use **MakerBundle**:

`composer req doctrine maker`

For example, create your entity:

`php bin/console make:entity Product`

If you want use `annotations`, run:

`composer req annotations`

...then you need this informations:

#### Examples the commands for to works with entities (database)

Symfony use [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

If your don't have database, run this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

If you want create entities in your database:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:create`

If your need update your entities, run this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

For help, run command:

`php bin/console list doctrine`

*So, your can generate entities if you already have database, see `list doctrine`.*

Answer (score 1):

Create a plain old PHP object, add some doctrine annotations to it for the properties which are columns, then do a `doctrine:migrations:diff`. A migration file will be created with the SQL required. Then you run `doctrine:migrations:migrate` and the SQL will be executed.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wondering is if there is still a way to interactively generate an entity and/or crud.

Why not use `maker`, which you mentioned?

```
 composer require maker --dev
```

Then, run:

```
bin/console make:entity
```

Comment: Since I've posted this question, the MakerBundle now supports `make:entity` and  `make:crud`. That answered my question. Thanks :)